# Возможно ли задать flexbox элементу высоту в процентах?

Tags: css

Возможно ли задать флексбокс элементу высоту в процентах?
Как можно регулировать высоту флексбокс элемента, кроме как заполнением его контентом и указания фиксированных значений для высоты?

Comment: пример кода приведите, про высоту где, чего и тд нам думать?

Answer (score 3):

Да. `flex-grow` и `flex-shrink` позволяют дополнительно управлять размерами.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: .5em;
}

div {
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style=height:20%></div>
<div style=height:20%></div>
<div style=height:20%></div>
<div style=height:40%></div>
<div style=height:40%></div>
<div style=height:80%></div>
<div style=height:20%></div>
<div style=height:60%></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то примерно так. Высота flexbox-parent может быть любая, при этом .flexbox-item.one равен 1/4, а .flexbox-item.two - 3/4

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexbox-parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.flexbox-item.one {
  flex: 1;
  background: #000;
}

.flexbox-item.two {
  flex: 3;
  background: #99c;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <div class="flexbox-item one">
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-item two">
  </div>
</div>
```